# Why did jQuery remove .toggle() method?

Tags: jquery, toggle

[.toggle( handler, handler [, handler ] )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/#toggle-handler-handler-handler)

I believe this API is very handy. But why jQuery 1.9 removed it?

Comment: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Answer (score 3):

It was deprecated in 1.8, as per [ticket # 11786](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786). It was later removed in 1.9.

Basically, that ticket contains the real reasons, such as:

> The `.toggle()` method is provided for convenience. It is relatively straightforward to implement the same behavior by hand, and this can be necessary if the assumptions built into `.toggle()` prove limiting.
>
> For example, `.toggle()` is not guaranteed to work correctly if applied twice to the same element.
>
> Since `.toggle()` internally uses a click handler to do its work, we must unbind click to remove a behavior attached with `.toggle()`, so other click handlers can be caught in the crossfire.
>
> The implementation also calls `.preventDefault()` on the event, so links will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked if `.toggle()` has been called on the element.