# Reveal text on hover with unique transition

Tags: css, button, text, transition, slide

I'm making a personal website and I'd like the main page to feature 4 buttons that use a CSS transition to 'grow' and reveal hidden text.

I've attached a picture to show you what I mean:

[image: Button Expansion]

So basically, if you hovered over it the left, right, and top borders would expand to reveal text. For now I'm just trying to achieve the effect and am not worried about making it an actual button, so I've been using the hover state.

The tricky ones are really just the top and bottom. The left and right ones just grow horizontally.

I've been messing around with this for a while which just scales horizontally:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <p>
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
        </p>
        <p>
        Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

#container #content {
max-width: 0px;
transition: max-width 0.15s ease-out;
overflow: hidden;
background: #d5d5d5;
}

#container:hover #content {
max-width: 500px;
transition: max-width 1s ease-in;
}
```

It's based off of someone else's code I found while searching for an answer. I understand what's going on here, but I can't figure out how to scale it. I would also lose the transition effect if I added max-height and set it to anything other than 0. Regardless, I'm going for something more complex and could use some guidance.

You think I'll need to write some JS to animate the button to expand from the bottom center? I found this which scales in all directions:

http://jsfiddle.net/xcWge/14/

Tried messing with specific margins, but wasn't getting any responsive results.

It's worth noting that I'm pretty new to all of this so I might be in over my head. I'm still determined to achieve this kind of functionality though. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please post your own code jsFiddle. I am not able to figure out the problem in given jsFiddle.

Comment: Have you tried `transform:scale(2);` as a CSS property?

Comment: @geeksal That was more of a starting off point or just a general idea of the behavior I'm looking. More than a definitive answer to this problem, I'm looking for direction or insight on how to accomplish this conceptually. Like I said, I'm new to front end development.

Comment: @fauxserious I was playing around with that feature after you suggested it and sort of achieved the behavior I was looking for, but couldn't figure out how to prevent the text within div from being scaled.

Comment: All you need to do is target the p tags inside with a negative scale value to bring it back down.

Comment: Scaling didn't work and it's too hacky anyway. I started writing it in JS and got a prototype working with the .click method. Of course I need it to toggle so I used .toggle instead and added another function to handle the second click. It doesn't work!

https://jsfiddle.net/0r81f7cv/1/

For some reason it's going straight to the second method and for some reason the button shrinks to nothing. No idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem and achieved a prototype of what I want. Here is the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/0r81f7cv/3/

Turns out this was the problem:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
```

I didn't figure this out until someone pointed it out to me FOUR days later, but JQuery depreciated the .toggle function after 1.9 which was causing the problems in the JSfiddle in my last comment. This seemed totally ridiculous to me until I read this:

[Why did jQuery remove .toggle() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052129/why-did-jquery-remove-toggle-method)

So, for those ever having a problem with code that is otherwise kosh, CHECK YOUR LIBRARY VERSION!